# Cross Join of Project Server odata REST query

Tags: rest, odata, project-server

I am trying to be efficient in my _api/projectdata rest query and get specific results from timesheet actuals. However, in someones great wisdom they didn't provide something as simple as the projectId in the properties. So I came up with the following not sure whether the cross join is supported but it doesn't puke. The issue is my results contain data that should be filtered. Is this format possible?

/epm/pma/_api/ProjectData/TimesheetLineActualDataSet?$select=ResourceName,ActualWorkBillable,TimeByDay&$crossjoin(TimesheetLine,TimesheetLineActualDataSet)&$apply=filter(TimesheetLine/ProjectId eq 'd8ba8b7e-3308-471c-a884-48f2116c803f' and TimesheetLine/TimesheetLineId eq TimesheetLineActualDataSet/TimesheetLineId and TimesheetLineActualDataSet/ActualWorkBillable > 0 and TimeByDay gt datetime'2017-10-01')

Comment: please disregard the > in the filter as it should be gt. Same issue.

Comment: Did you try adding a $select parameter to the query string?